# small example of sql query

Tags: sql

I am new in sql queries.

I am working on the transaction with databases.

I want to write a sql query which will insert only those numbers which are starting from 101.

```
sql = "insert into tablex where values 101123";
sql = "insert into tablex where values 10100";  
sql = "insert into tablex where values 101125";
```

All inserts should happnd with values which starts with 101 only.
the numbers 101123, 10100, 101123 comes from a text file with some program.

I want to only insert those numbers which starts with 101 in table.

Comment: i have tried sql queries but i dt know how can i use if statement in sql query

Comment: why -ve marking unnecessary when u cant answer question?

Comment: You should use whatever language that is reading in the data from the file to filter the values you want to insert into your table. IF you had provided this information when you first posted you probably would have gotten a better response. Go back and reread your original posting. Would you have know how to help debug your own question without any other information? NO. Even now your question doesn't have all the info such as which language you are using. Don't expect others to be mind readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the records inserted by using a `WHERE` clause on your query.

```
insert into yourtable (col1)
select yourColumn
from yourtable
where yourColumn >= 101
```

Based on your comments, maybe you want something like this:

```
insert into yourtable (col1)
select yourColumn
from yourtable
where yourColumn LIKE '101%'
```

Comment: i dt want to insert from table. i am inserting just integer values

Comment: you can use the following: `INSERT INTO yourtable (col1) VALUES (101);`

Comment: i need integet values starting with 101 means 10135, 1015698, 10142, etc

Comment: your question is not complete, please explain where data is coming from and how you are calling that sql (database or any application)

Comment: @sam you need to provide more details then.  Please edit your OP with more details.

Comment: @sam where are the values coming from?

Comment: I am entering those values randomly lets say from a .txt file

Comment: filter them before calling your sql in your code that reads from text file